# how to attach variable inside a dictonary in django application

Tags: python, html, django

```
{% with alertnames as name %}
{{name}}
```

I have data in this variable `{{name}}` and now If I want to attach in a dictionary as `"Dictonary.name"` and display it.How can I do that?

Comment: *attach in a dictionary*?

Comment: Looks like something you should be doing in the view not in the template.

Comment: Actually I have a dictonary which is returing{Message': 'Yes', 'alertPresentFile': [u'Missing', 'Message'], Missing': u'No'}
Now when i try to parse and print this dict and write
{% for name in dictonaty.alertPresentFile %}
I get the values .Now my requirment is to pass this particluar name like "{{dictionary.name}}" which I am unable to fetch.How to get this particular thing

Comment: You're going to have show more code. what is `alertnames`? Are you adding a value to your dictionary or just to the `alertPresentFile` key?

Comment: the main issue is if I try to access the values in dictionary as {{dictionary.Message}} I get the value as "Yes"
but the same thing if I try to {{dictionary.name}} where name is the variable.Then it does not get displayed @mangoHero1

Comment: It has to be set to a value before you can call it. If there's no key named `name`, you must create one. If passed in Python, you can do `dictionary["name"] = "someName"` *then* you can call `dictionary.name`. the `with` block is not necessary

Comment: @Mangohero1 Is it like we cannot access items like this in dictionary??

Comment: `dictionary.name` is how you access the item, yes. But since, by itself, the dictionary doesn't have a key called `name`, it needs to be *assigned* before it can be accessed.

Comment: But I wanted it to be a dynamic.Is there any possiblility of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are rendering like

```
{'Message': 'Yes', 'alertPresentFile': [u'Missing', 'Message'], 'Missing': u'No'}
```

So if you want to do like {{data.Message}}

```
{'data': {'Message': 'Yes', 'alertPresentFile': [u'Missing', 'Message'], 'Missing': u'No'}}
```